# What is the "Browser" process?

Tags: 12.04, firefox, browser, process

What is the Browser process?

Is the process safe or malicious?

Thanks for help,

Top results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To know from what folder this Process is running :

```
   sudo ls -l /proc/<Pid>/cwd
```

In your case Pid is  **24916**

So you can know what is this "Browser"